go-redis - set hash with nested Struct
With the example code below, Redis ( using go-redis ) stores:

I want to store the nested "Bite" struct in the hash of the original.  At the moment, the only solutions I see from other posts suggest using a different Data Structure with Redis ( something like JSON, YAML to keep the entire Struct and nested Structs ) or create a sub-Hash related to the first by the key ( i.e. insect:blackwidow:bite" ).
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
)

type Bite struct {
    Power string `redis:"power"`
    Toxic bool `redis:"toxic"`
}

type Insect struct {
    Name        string `redis:"name"`
    Description string `redis:"description"`
    Bite        Bite
    Legs        int `redis:"legs"`
}

func main() {

    var insects []Insect
    err := json.Unmarshal(MockSpidersResponse, &insects)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    client, err := InitRedis()
    if err != nil {panic(err)}

    ctx := context.Background()


    for _, i := range insects {
        if err := client.HSet(ctx, "insect:"+i.Name, i).Err(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}


 

/* JSON being read
[
  {
    "name": "blackwidow",
    "description": "small but deadly",
    "Bite": {
      "Power": "deadly",
      "toxic": true
    },
    "legs": 8
  },
  {
    "name": "daddylonglegs",
    "description": "long and thin. harmless",
    "Bite": {
      "Power": "can't bite",
      "toxic": false
    },
    "legs": 8
  }
]
 */


I solved it by using unmarshal, before I got close to go-redis.

type Bite struct {
    Power string `json:"power"`
    Toxic bool   `json:"toxic"`
}

type InsectJSON struct {
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Bite        Bite
    Legs        int `json:"legs"`
}

type Insect struct {
    Name        string `redis:"name"`
    Description string `redis:"description"`
    Power       string `redis:"power"`
    Toxic       bool   `redis:"toxic"`
    Legs        int    `redis:"legs"`
}

func (i *Insect) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var ij InsectJSON
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &ij); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    i.Name = ij.Name
    i.Description = ij.Description
    i.Power = ij.Bite.Power
    i.Toxic = ij.Bite.Toxic
    i.Legs = ij.Legs

    return nil
}

